# Perform function if string exists on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply want to have an alert that says "Page contains string" if a specific string exists on a page.

Shouldn't it be as simple as this:

```
if ('*:contains("This String")') {
    alert('Page Contains String');
}
```

Comment: Missed to add jQuery lib(usually a `dollar symbol`),  `$('*:contains("This String")')` or `jQuery('*:contains("This String")')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way :

```
if($("body").text().indexOf("This String") > -1) {
    alert("page contains string");
}
```

Or pure JS :

```
if (~document.body.textContent.indexOf('This String')) {
    alert("page contains string");
}
```

Comment: Ooh, you downvoted me because you've also got an answer here.
Instead of using `>`, try not to use jQuery.

Comment: ... Always go for readable code. `~` is not developer-friendly.
And did you seriously leave out the compatibility code you downvoted me for not having?

Answer (score 7):

Native JS:

```
if(document.body.innerText.indexOf("This String") !== -1){
    // Do stuff
}
```

You might want to use [`document.body.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) instead, though. Depending on what browsers you want / need to support. (`textContent` is not supported by IE 8 or lower.)

For maximum compatibility, try this:

```
var text = document.body.innerText || document.body.textContent;
if(text.indexOf("This String") !== -1){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: You should use the '>' comparator instead of '!==', it will be faster.

Comment: @Apolo: Did you really just downvote me for such a micro optimization? Then downvote the other 2 answers for using jQuery.

Comment: Guys, really? 2 Downvotes? At least comment with a good reason on what's so bad about my answer.

Comment: @Apolo talking about optimization but suggesting using jQuery.. (facepalm)

Comment: nope, as your edit mentionned, I would recommend using textContent which is supported by all recent navigator. Or this way : `txt = div.textContent || div.innerText || '';`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown he is asking for a JQuery solution (see tag). Also `$("body")` is not a huge loss of performance.

Comment: @Apolo, nope.. the difference between `<` and `!==` that have huge loss performance.

Comment: @Apolo: He's just saying jQuery is an option. Also, `document.body` is [**so very much faster**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-body-vs-document-body-selector/26), it's not even anywhere near close. (It's **50** times as fast!)

Comment: @Apolo: I added a compatibility option, so your downvote is no longer valid. Could you remove it please? \[edit] Thanks! [/edit]

Comment: Done. Also, another good answer related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/3484498 See first comment. I add a pure JS solution based on that to my answer so downvote should be removed too I guess.

Answer (score 2):

create a string of the html

```
//Retrieves html string
var htmlString = $('body').html();
```

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. This method returns `-1` if the value to search for never occurs.

```
var index = htmlString.indexOf("this string");

if (index != -1)
    alert("contains string");
```

**One-Liner**

```
if($('body').html().indexOf("this string") !== -1)
     alert("contains string")
```

Comment: I think there is no need to cast the result of `.html()` to string since it already returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another method with jQuery -

```
if( $('body:contains(string)').length ) {
    console.log('found it');
};
```

Your syntax is a little messed up, but you were on the right path.

```
if ( $('*:contains("This String")').length ) { // you needed an alias to jQuery, some proper parentheses and you must test for length
    alert('Page Contains String');
}
```

testable here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/zg75Z/